# SQL multiple results loop

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops

I have two databases. The first database my main database, the second database is used to import fragments of badly structured data in JSON format. I import the badly structured data into the second database to give the data some basic structure before importing it into my main database.

The first database contains forty-three tables. The second database consists of four tables.  Below I will discuss the relevant tables.

```
Database1   Database2
Table1      Table1
Table2      Table2
Table3
```

Currently I try to import data from the second database into Table1. Table1 consists out of five columns (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5). Columns 1 to 4 are the primary key and are set to `NOT NULL`.

To fill the columns 1 to 5, I call Database1 tables 2 and 3 and Database2 tables 1 and 2 with the following SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO DB1.Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
SELECT DISTINCT D1T2.Col6, D1T3Col7, D2T1Col8, D2T1Col9, D2T1Col10
FROM Database1.Table2 AS D1T2, Database1.Table3 AS D1T3, Database2.Table1 AS D2T1
WHERE D1T2.Col6 IN (SELECT DISTINCT COL6 FROM Database1.Table2
WHERE (Col11, Col12) IN (SELECT DISTINCT Col13, Col14 FROM Database2.Table2))
AND D1T3.Col7 IN (SELECT DISTINCT COL7 FROM Database1.Table3 WHERE (Col15)
IN (SELECT DISTINCT Col16 FROM Database2.Table1));
```

When I run the above code on some sample data I’m expecting three results. Unfortunately, I’m getting nine different results. Below an example of the results I’m expecting followed by the results I’m getting.

Expected results:

```
Database1.Table1

Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
Val1    Val6    Val7    Val8    Va9
Val1    Val10   Val11   Val12   Val13
```

Actual results:

```
Database1.Table1

Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
Val1    Val2    Val7    Val8    Va9
Val1    Val2    Val11   Val12   Val13
Val1    Val6    Val3    Val4    Val5
Val1    Val6    Val7    Val8    Va9
Val1    Val6    Val11   Val12   Val13
Val1    Val10   Val3    Val4    Val5
Val1    Val10   Val7    Val8    Va9
Val1    Val10   Val11   Val12   Val13
```

I guess this means the SQL code is looping somewhere. As I’m not really familiar with (My)SQL, what can I do to only get three results?

Running the code in multiple statements is a no-go since it produces error #1452

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

If you need some more information I will be happy to add it to this post.

EDIT: Edited in some addition information and clarification.

EDIT: In the following SQL-code I used JOINS and gave me the correct results:

```
INSERT INTO DB1.Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
SELECT DB1.Table2.Col1, DB1.Table3.Col2, DB2.Table2.Col8, DB2.Table2.Col9, DB2.Table2.Col10
FROM DB1.Table2
        JOIN DB2.Table1 ON
            Table2.Col11 = Table1.Col13 AND
            Table2.Col12 = Table1.Col14,
    DB1.Table3
        Join DB2.Table2 ON
        Table3.Col15 = Table2.Col16;
```

Comment: The rows that return are duplicated? or 9 different values? I have a feeling you are just missing a join condition

Comment: I'm getting nine different values. I will edit my OP with an example.

Comment: Sagi, thanks for pointing out joins as I was unfamiliar with them. Changing the SQL with joins solved my problems.